# iOS minimum system

Tags: ios

I'm about to update my iPad app.  I've not added any new features from iOS 6, however, one of my testers is telling me that he cannot update because he's stuck on 5.1 with a iPad 1.  My project's BaseSDK is set to 6.0, however the deployment target is set to 5.1.  I would think that that should still work for iOS 5?  What am I missing?

Comment: does infoDictionary version have anything to do with this?  that is set to 6.0.

Comment: What exactly happens on that testers device? Is he not able to install the app at all, does it crash or what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your target's Deployment target. This can be different than the project's deployment target. A Deployment target of 5.1 for the target will allow the app to run on a device with iOS 5.1.

Comment: Nope, both deployment targets are set to 5.1.  thanks though!